# Reading from serial port in the simplest way?

Tags: serial-port

I have a [TrueRNG](http://ubld.it/products/truerng-hardware-random-number-generator/) USB-based hardware RNG, and I am trying to read its output on Mac OS X 10.9.2.  I need just one-way communication.

The device says that it appears as a "CDC Virtual Serial Port", and indeed I see it as `/dev/tty.usbmodem1411`.

I've never been able to `cat /dev/tty.usbmodem1411`; when I do, I get no output at all.  I can, however, use `minicom` or `picocom` to read from it.  With `picocom`, it works even with `--noinit --noreset` options, suggesting that I *should* be able to `cat` that device.

So, my issues/questions:

1. Why can I not `cat` that device?
2. Though it works with `minicom` and `picocom`, it works just on the first session: if I close either of these programs, then reopen them, then they read about 300 bytes and block forever.  If I close and reopen *again*, they can't read anything.  When I unplug and replug the USB device, though, it's again readable forever on the first attempt.  Why would this be, and does it have to do with this quote from TrueRNG documentation? "By clearing the DTR flag on the virtual serial port, the stream of data will stop. The stream of data will resume when DTR is set."
3. I want to view the random data in hex.  So I try this command: `picocom /dev/tty.usbmodem1411 | xxd -p`.  The output, however, doesn't seem to respect the newline character; just the carriage return.  It moves to the next line without rewinding to the beginning of the line.  I'd prefer it to be continuous.

Here's some diagnostics:

```
% stty -a -f /dev/tty.usbmodem1411
speed 9600 baud; 0 rows; 0 columns;
lflags: -icanon -isig -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoke -echonl
        -echoctl -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho -pendin
        -nokerninfo -extproc
iflags: -istrip -icrnl -inlcr -igncr -ixon -ixoff -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
        -ignbrk -brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: -opost -onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb crtscts -dsrflow
        -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
        eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
        min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
        stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

Comment: Can you try with cat /dev/tty.usbmodem1411 | hexdump -C (with cat you may be able to read from it, but quite a few characters are not  printable). In addition, you could use dd if=/dev/tty.usbmodem1411

Comment: Nikolaidis, thanks for your comment. Like I mentioned, with `cat` I cannot read from it.  Absolutely no data comes out, whether printable or unprintable.  Same for `dd`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I needed to use `/dev/cu.usbmodem1234` instead of `dev/tty.usbmodem1234`.  Thanks for [the solution](http://ubld.it/forums/topic/truerng-on-mac-osx-10-9/#post-718) to the company that manufactures this device.

Comment: That article, in turn, references back to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632586/macos-whats-the-difference-between-dev-tty-and-dev-cu